# Sorting 20 newsgroup dataset in python

Tags: python, text, machine-learning

in the code below I tried to sort the 20 newsgroup datasets. But it provides error. The wondering part is the dimensionality of this array (11314, 130107). Anyone knows why?

```
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf

from pprint import pprint

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups_vectorized

data_train= fetch_20newsgroups_vectorized(subset='train')

temp= np.sort(data_train.data, axis=1)
```

Comment: The error that I get is AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0. But as I said above the dimensionality is (11314, 130107)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [fetch_20newsgroup_vectorized](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_20newsgroups_vectorized.html) described, it returns a csr_matrix other than np.matrix:

> Returns bunch : Bunch object
>   bunch.data: sparse matrix, shape [n_samples, n_features] bunch.target: array, shape [n_samples] bunch.target_names: list, length [n_classes]

You need to transfer it into np.matrix with [todense](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html):

```
np.sort(data_train.data.todense(), axis=1)
```